# Input Placeholder Text Color

Tags: css

I have a contact form and I would like to change the color of placeholder to white. I tried adding classes via CSS, but I have failed.

```
<input type="text" name="FullName" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required cnt_inp1" aria-required="true"   aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Full Name*">
```

If somebody could explain me and give me the solution, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 3):

There are different CSS styles depending on the browser. This would do what you want in all major browsers (this would style all inputs, you can individualize them as well):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#f00; }
::-moz-placeholder { color:#f00; } /* firefox */
:-ms-input-placeholder { color:#f00; } /* ie */
input:-moz-placeholder { color:#f00; }
```